# Left join combining GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below tables and i trying to `LEFT JOIN` from table A to table B to get `Code` & `Time`. The issue is that i get multiple lines for each code. What i want to get is one row for each `Code` with the `Time` which i less than the GETDATE () ordering desc.

**Tables:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
SELECT
      [ID],
      Date_Time
    FROM Table_A
    LEFT JOIN Table_B
      ON A.ID = B.Project_Code
```

Comment: Please take the time to post sample data has `text`; you should not expect the users here to have to transcribe your image to test. Also show us what your expected results should look like in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a cross apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.code = a.code and b.time < getdate()
      order by b.time desc
     ) b;
```

This assumes that `time` is really a `datetime`.  If you just want to compare times, then use `convert(time, getdate())`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have noticed something that i want to improve. The query exclude `Code` appears in table A which `Time` is greater than the current time. it there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Error1004 . . . Use `outer apply` instead of `cross apply`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra join clause to only return records from table before the specified `DATETIME`,then  simply use `MAX` to get the latest:

```
SELECT  a.[ID],
        Date_Time = MAX(b.Date_Time)
FROM    Table_A AS a
        LEFT JOIN Table_B AS b
          ON b.Project_Code = a.ID
          AND b.Date_Time < GETDATE()
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

If the column `Date_time` uses the `TIME` data type (your sample data suggests it does, but your column name suggests it does not), then you will need to convert `GETDATE()` to a time:

```
SELECT  a.[ID],
        Date_Time = MAX(b.Date_Time)
FROM    Table_A AS a
        LEFT JOIN Table_B AS b
          ON b.Project_Code = a.ID
          AND b.Date_Time < CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE())
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

If there are other columns you need to return from `Table_B`, then you will need to use `OUTER APPLY`, or a subquery with a ranking function.

**OUTER APPLY**

```
SELECT  a.[ID],
        b.Date_Time,
        b.SomeOtherColumn
FROM    Table_A AS a
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 b.Date_Time, b.SomeOtherColumn
            FROM    Table_B AS b
            WHERE   A.ID = B.Project_Code
            AND     b.Date_Time < GETDATE()
            ORDER BY b.Date_Time DESC
        ) AS b;
```

**SUBQUERY WITH RANKING FUNCTION**

```
SELECT  a.[ID],
        b.Date_Time,
        b.SomeOtherColumn
FROM    Table_A AS a
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  b.Project_Code,
                    b.Date_Time, 
                    b.SomeOtherColumn,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.Project_Code ORDER BY b.Date_Time DESC)
            FROM    Table_B AS b
            WHERE   b.Date_Time < GETDATE()
            ORDER BY b.Date_Time DESC
        ) AS b
            ON b.Project_Code = a.ID
            AND b.RowNumber = 1;
```